# reading text file column by column each in a different array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have this text file

```
 SFrm  EFrm   SegAScr Phone
    0    36   -158051 SIL
   37   105   -644247 +NONTRANS+
  106   109    -96452 l SIL w b
  110   112   -125055 w l aa i
  113   115   -150550 aa w 7 i
  116   118   -146662 7 aa i i
  119   122    -46757 i 7 d i
  123   126    -58440 d i SIL e
  127   146    -90776 +MUSIC+
  147   152    -61098 t SIL u b
  153   158    -67393 u t f i
  159   174   -251284 f u f i
  175   178    -79772 f f aa i
  179   194   -134562 aa f 7 i
  195   206    -33695 7 aa a i
  207   223   -194024 a 7 SIL e
  224   350   -434997 +NOISE+
  351   353    -28280 SIL
 Total score:    -2802095
```

I managed to store this whole thing in a string but I need to store it in some arrays where Each column is represented in a different array I know that I can use .split() as a procedure to convert it into array but I won't be able to discard the spaces between columns.

**ps: the text file is generic so these numbers and letters are not constants but the form of it is constant (4 columns)**

My main problem now is to catch the duplicate vowels when they are at the beginning of any row in the fourth column and do some calculations with the numbers at the same row if someone has easier approach than mine any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You need to read the file line by line, split the line and store the values in their respective arrays.

Comment: Spaces in your file data is real messy, Is there any way you can change the format of data lie csv. Else it is going to be hard for you to split.

Comment: Are these columns fixed-width?

Comment: In a more object oriented fashion, you would not split each line into 1 entry in each of 4 arrays; you would read a line and create an _object_ from that line, and keep a single array (or `List`) of objects. Maybe use a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to pick each line apart.

Comment: @denis I can't change this file is an output of engine I'm working on which is sphinx3_aligner

Comment: @fateddy no the columns are not fixed-width they may vary if I ran the engine with another input

Comment: @fateddy if I misunderstood you and you meant by fixed width (the number of columns) so yes its fixed width

Comment: I would also suggest read line by line split it and save it in their respective arrays.

Comment: @Beeee no - I was asking if the columns do have a fixed width (eg. width of column 1 is 4 characters, column 2 is 6 chars etc) - basically to know when to split.

Comment: @fateddy no they are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

          FileReader inputFile = new FileReader("input");

          //Instantiate the BufferedReader Class
          BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

          //Variable to hold the one line data
          String line="";int index=0;

          String[] column1= new String[100];
          String[] column2 = new String[100];
          String[] column3=new String[100];
          String[] column4=new String[100];



          while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null){

              String temp="";int count=1;
              column4[index]="";
              //System.out.println(line);
               StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line," ");
              //String tokenizer gets the token from each space
               while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                 { 

                   temp = st.nextToken();
                    //System.out.println(temp);
                  If(temp.equals("Total")){
                      break;
                  }

                  if(count==1)
                  {
                 // System.out.println(temp);
                  column1[index] = temp;
                  }
                 if(count==2){
                  column2[index] = temp;
                   }   
                 if(count==3)
                {
                  column3[index] = temp;
                 }
                if(count==4)
                {
                column4[index] += temp;
                }
               if(count<4)
                  count++;
                }


             index++;              
           }

          for(int i=0;i<index-1;i++){
              System.out.println(column1[i]+" "+column2[i]+" "+column3[i]+" "+column4[i]);
          }

       }
```

I declared four arrays to store the columns from above data as you wanted. I am using stringTokenizer to get each token of string. I got this output when I printed the data from above array:

```
  SFrm EFrm SegAScr Phone
  0 36 -158051 SIL
  37 105 -644247 +NONTRANS+
  106 109 -96452 lSILwb
  110 112 -125055 wlaai
  113 115 -150550 aaw7i
  116 118 -146662 7aaii
  119 122 -46757 i7di
  123 126 -58440 diSILe
  127 146 -90776 +MUSIC+
  147 152 -61098 tSILub
  153 158 -67393 utfi
  159 174 -251284 fufi
  175 178 -79772 ffaai
  179 194 -134562 aaf7i
  195 206 -33695 7aaai
  207 223 -194024 a7SILe
  224 350 -434997 +NOISE+
  351 353 -28280 SIL
```

Comment: I really appreciated your hard work man thanks for that but I didn't clarify my 4 columns my bad !

Comment: You can make modifications in the code for fourth colum.

Comment: I really appreciated your hard work man thanks for that but I didn't clarify my 4 columns my bad ! my 4 columns are (SFrm -> 351) second is (Efrm -> 353) .third is (SegAScr -> -28280) , and finally the fourth one is   (Phone ->SIL ) Discarding Total score row which has its first word in an array only for it in your implementation. I am really sorry for my bad clarification and thanks again for your help I will try to modify your to achieve what I need. Thanks

Comment: All these four columns are in column arrays of my code.first column in first array ,second in second array and so on.

Comment: What's not according to your requirement?

Comment: I actually I am trying to understand your code and how you store your the data. Its a bit complicated for me cause I never used string tokenizers before :)

Comment: I just want to make the four arrays SFrm , Efrm, SegAScr ,Phone discarding that line 'Total score: -2802095' I cant avoid it in your code I am trying right now.

Comment: Okay but I can tell you those four columns you described are in those four arrays. In the fourth column I did not consider spaces.they are all concatenated into one. If you them same as input file you can modify that part. I think adding one space in the end of each assignment should do that.

Comment: Total score must be in the last index of first three arrays. Just assign an empty string to that.

Comment: what I am trying to do now is to create a new array for "Phone" column and discard the array which contains the word Total .

Comment: here is my code after modification there is one weird something happening  when printing fourth column before every column there is null word written . I mean for example nullPhone ,
nullSIL